# Where are Scala the compiler api docs from maintenance releases?

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, documentation, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to find full documentation of how to use scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop as it is defined in 2.9.3.  You can download the nightly compiler docs from the scala website, and you can download the 2.9.3 scala api docs, but I don't see the 2.9.3 compiler docs. Is my only recourse to build the docs from the 2.9.3 source? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just grab it from Maven Central:

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.scala-lang|scala-compiler|2.9.3|jar

(separate jars for binary, source and javadoc)

Answer (score 1):

I would have said clone the repo,

```
$ git checkout v2.9.3

$ ant docscomp
```

but I'm getting errors (on the order of missing classes and dir; but I'm not in a position ATM to try scrubbing).  Good luck!

Updated:

```
apm@mara:~/tmp$ whence bigant
bigant is aliased to `ANT_OPTS="${DEFAULT_ANT_OPTS}" ant'
apm@mara:~/tmp$ echo $DEFAULT_ANT_OPTS
-Xms1536M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:MaxPermSize=192M -XX:+UseParallelGC
```

I only use bigant; though, since this is my only use of ant these days, I could simplify a bit:

```
apm@mara:~/projects/snytt$ bigant all.clean ; bigant
Buildfile: /home/apm/projects/snytt/build.xml
     [echo] Forking with JVM opts: -Xms1536M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:MaxPermSize=192M -XX:+UseParallelGC
```

In case my error helps.  I'll update again when I pursue it. (I never build 2.9.)  It looks like jar refactoring.

```
/home/apm/projects/snytt/build.xml:354: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/home/apm/projects/snytt/lib/scala-compiler.jar!/scala/tools/ant/sabbus/antlib.xml:9: taskdef A class needed by class scala.tools.ant.sabbus.ScalacFork cannot be found: scala/tools/nsc/io/Path
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[/home/apm/projects/snytt/lib/scala-library.jar:/home/apm/projects/snytt/lib/scala-compiler.jar:/home/apm/projects/snytt/lib/fjbg.jar:/home/apm/projects/snytt/lib/forkjoin.jar:/home/apm/projects/snytt/lib/msil.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar]
```

Comment: you have to set the jvm options with `ANT_OPTS ="-Xms1536M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:MaxPermSize=192M -XX:+UseParallelGC"`, at least it was needed in past.